# Anaconda: Failed to create process. Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string

Tags: anaconda

My anaconda navigator has been working fine until I installed Spyder. Now, I am unable to open Anaconda Navigator and when I open up Anaconda Prompt, I kept getting the error shown in the image below. Everytime I enter something into the prompt, it throws me the same error, "Failed to create process. Invoke-Expression: Cannot bind argument to parameter "Command" because it is an empty string". As I have other environments in Anaconda, I don't want to reinstall Anaconda, unless it is really necessary.

[image]

Hope that someone can advise. Thank you.